# Django Complex MySQL Query From PHP with Multiple Joins to Django ORM

Tags: sql, django, orm, kohana

I have this code from Kohana (it's easily understandable) and I want to convert this to Django ORM given the ff. models:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    glasses = models.ManyToManyField(Glass, through="ItemGlass")
    collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection)

class ItemGlass(models.Model):
    glass = models.ForeignKey(Glass)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)

class Collection(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Code(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.TextField()

class Glass(models.Model):
    collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection)
    code = models.ForeignKey(Code)
```

and the php query (uses Kohana's Database Lib)

```
$this->select(
                array('cd.id', 'id'), 
                array('cd.description','description'),
                array('COUNT(DISTINCT("items.id"))', 'count')
            )
                    ->from('items')
            ->join(array('collections', 'c'))
            ->on('c.id', '=', 'items.collection_id')
            ->join(array('glasses', 'g'))
            ->on('g.collection_id', '=', 'c.id')
            ->join(array('code', 'cd'))
            ->on('cd.id', '=', 'g.code_id')
            ->where('items.discontinued', '=', FALSE)
            ->group_by('cd.id');
```

**NOTE:** the "array" clause you see is translated as

```
"SELECT cd.id AS id, cd.description AS description, COUNT(DISTINCT(items.id) AS count"
```

The thing is how do I do it? I can't successfully use select_related to join multiple tables in this case, and I can't find a good "filter trick" for the query. Any ideas?

**EDIT:** I am considering doing it in plain SQL, but I would prefer to avoid it if a Django ORM query can be done :)

Comment: Why the `ItemGlass` model? Are the more attributes on it that you left out for simplification?

Comment: ItemGLass is a "through" table, storing additional data. some attributes are left out for simplification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have come up with this after an hour of "head banging":

```
glasses = Code.objects.filter(glass__collection__item__discontinued=False)\
        .values('id', 'description')\
        .annotate(count=Count('glass__collection__item__id', distinct=True))
```

Comment: You are aware that this makes `glasses` a QuerySet containing `Code` objects.

Comment: this was copied from a PHP code, the variable naming must be wrong but I'll keep it as is to maintain that this PHP query translates to this django query

Comment: This just illustrates the power of the django queryset API does it not?

Comment: *NB* you might consider gradually moving away from using \ for line continuation -- it's [not officially recommended](http://docs.python.org/dev/howto/doanddont.html#using-backslash-to-continue-statements) due to the possibility of introducing subtle problems, there are better alternatives (here, you could rely on the implicit line continuation from parentheses) and in fact this feature was [almost removed from Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3125/) entirely!

Answer (score 0):

Definitely don't use SQL, it's a simple query which should be no problem with the ORM. Use something like:

```
Code.objects.filter(glass__item__discontinued=False) \
    .annotate(count=models.Count('glass__item__id'))
```

You can add a `.values(...)` to the end of it if you only want to retrieve specific columns, as in your php example.

Comment: [`aggregate()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/aggregation/#aggregating-annotations) is used to aggregate annotations.. `annotate()` should be used here.

Comment: Your Count() call should have distinct=True as well